# Why is this program not writing the output files to the chosen path?

Tags: pysimplegui

I would like the output files of this program to be saved in the path that the user picks. I have tried cleaning up my code but it is not saving the code in the chosen directory. I would like the output files of this program to be saved in the path that the user picks.I would like the output files of this program to be saved in the path that the user picks. I have tried cleaning up my code but it is not saving the code in the chosen directory.

```
from pathlib import Path
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
import csv

sg.theme('Dark')

binFile1=binFile2=binFile3=binFile4=binFile5=binFile6=binFile7=binFile8 = None
binFile9=binFile10=binFile11=binFile12=binFile13=binFile14=binFile15=binFile16 = None

def open_output_files(num_bytes):
    global binFile1, binFile2, binFile3, binFile4, binFile5, binFile6, binFile7, binFile8, \
           binFile9, binFile10, binFile11, binFile12, binFile13, binFile14, binFile15, binFile16
    try:
        count = int(num_bytes)
    except ValueError:
        count = 16
    if not (0 <= count <= 15):
        count = 16
    return [open(f"{157+i}.bin", "wb") for i in range(count)]

layouts = [
    [   # Layout 0
        [sg.Text('How many driver bits do you need? (Enter a number between 1 and 71)')],
        [sg.Input(key='-IN0-', expand_x=True, enable_events=True)],
        [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT0-')],
        [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Next >', key='Next 0')]],
    [   # Layout 1
        [sg.Text('Choose .CSV File')],
        [sg.Input(key='-IN1-'), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("All Excel Files", "*.csv"), ))],
        [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT1-')],
        [sg.Button('< Prev', key='Prev 1'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Submit', key='Next 1')]],
    [   # Layout 2
        [sg.Text('Please choose where you would like to export the .BIN files...')],
        [sg.Input(key='-IN2-', expand_x=True), sg.FolderBrowse()],
        [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT2-')],
        [sg.Button('< Prev', key='Prev 2'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Next >', key='Next 2')]],
    [   # Layout 3
        [sg.Text('Please go back and verify your settings. \nIf everything looks correct, click Write!.')],
        [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT3-')],
        [sg.Button('< Prev', key='Prev 3'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Write!', key='Next 3')]],
    [   # Layout 4
        [sg.Text('Compilation Complete! \nYour files have been saved in your chosen directory.')],
        [sg.Text('Finish !', expand_x=True, justification='center')],
        [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Exit')]],
]

layout = [[sg.Column(item, visible=(i==0), key=f'Column {i}') for i, item in enumerate(layouts)]]
window = sg.Window('CSV to Binary', layout, enable_close_attempted_event=True)
column = 0

def show(step):
    global column
    window[f'Column {column}'].update(visible=False)
    column += step
    window[f'Column {column}'].update(visible=True)
    window.refresh()
    window.move_to_center()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT:
        if column in (0, 4):
            break
        else:
            show(-1)
    elif event in ('Exit', 'Finish!'):
        break
    elif event.startswith("Prev"):
        show(-1)
    elif event.startswith("Next"):
        show(+1)
    elif event == 'Top':
        show(-4)
    
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Write!':
       filename = values['-IN1-']
       if Path(filename).is_file():
        print(filename)   
        start_time = time.time()        
        init = True    
        linecnt = 0
        numfiles = round[int(values('-IN0-' % 8))]
        open_output_files(numfiles) # MODIFY THIS TO BE # OF BURN IN CHANNELS / 8 (Round up!!!)
        filename = open('-IN1-')
        
        with open(filename, "rb") as vecfile:
            vectors = csv.reader(vecfile, delimiter = ',')    
        for vec in vectors:
            if(linecnt < 0):
                next
            else: 
                temp_vec = ''
                for i in range(0,72):
                    temp_vec += vec[i]
                temp_vec = temp_vec.translate({ord(x): '0' for x in ['Z', 'X', 'H', 'L']})  
                vec_str = temp_vec + ''
                #vec_str = vec_str[::-1, 2]  
                if numfiles == 1: 
                    byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)
                    binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                    binFile1.close()
                elif numfiles == 2: 
                    byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                    byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)
                    binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                    binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                    binFile1.close()
                    binFile2.close()
                elif numfiles == 3: 
                     byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                     byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)    
                     byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)
                     binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile1.close()
                     binFile2.close()
                     binFile3.close()
                elif numfiles == 4: 
                     byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                     byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)    
                     byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)     
                     byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
                     binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile1.close()
                     binFile2.close()
                     binFile3.close()
                     binFile4.close()
                elif numfiles == 5: 
                     byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                     byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)    
                     byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)     
                     byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
                     byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)
                     binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile5.write(byte5.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile1.close()
                     binFile2.close()
                     binFile3.close()
                     binFile4.close()
                     binFile5.close()
                elif numfiles == 6: 
                     byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                     byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)    
                     byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)     
                     byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
                     byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)    
                     byte6 = int(vec_str[47:39:-1],2)
                     binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile5.write(byte5.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile6.write(byte6.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile1.close()
                     binFile2.close()
                     binFile3.close()
                     binFile4.close()
                     binFile5.close()
                     binFile6.close()
                elif numfiles == 7: 
                     byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                     byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)    
                     byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)     
                     byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
                     byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)    
                     byte6 = int(vec_str[47:39:-1],2)
                     byte7 = int(vec_str[55:47:-1],2)
                     binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile5.write(byte5.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile6.write(byte6.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile7.write(byte7.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile1.close()
                     binFile2.close()
                     binFile3.close()
                     binFile4.close()
                     binFile5.close()
                     binFile6.close()
                     binFile7.close()
                elif numfiles == 8: 
                     byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                     byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)    
                     byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)     
                     byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
                     byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)    
                     byte6 = int(vec_str[47:39:-1],2)
                     byte7 = int(vec_str[55:47:-1],2)
                     byte8 = int(vec_str[63:55:-1],2)
                     binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile5.write(byte5.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile6.write(byte6.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile7.write(byte7.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile8.write(byte8.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile1.close()
                     binFile2.close()
                     binFile3.close()
                     binFile4.close()
                     binFile5.close()
                     binFile6.close()
                     binFile7.close()
                     binFile8.close()
                elif numfiles == 9: 
                     byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                     byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)    
                     byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)     
                     byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
                     byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)    
                     byte6 = int(vec_str[47:39:-1],2)
                     byte7 = int(vec_str[55:47:-1],2)
                     byte8 = int(vec_str[63:55:-1],2)
                     byte9 = int(vec_str[71:63:-1],2)
                     binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile5.write(byte5.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile6.write(byte6.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile7.write(byte7.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile8.write(byte8.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile9.write(byte9.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile1.close()
                     binFile2.close()
                     binFile3.close()
                     binFile4.close()
                     binFile5.close()
                     binFile6.close()
                     binFile7.close()
                     binFile8.close()
                     binFile9.close()
                elif numfiles == 10: 
                     byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                     byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)    
                     byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)     
                     byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
                     byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)    
                     byte6 = int(vec_str[47:39:-1],2)
                     byte7 = int(vec_str[55:47:-1],2)
                     byte8 = int(vec_str[63:55:-1],2)
                     byte9 = int(vec_str[71:63:-1],2)
                     byte10 = int(vec_str[79:71:-1],2)
                     binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile5.write(byte5.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile6.write(byte6.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile7.write(byte7.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile8.write(byte8.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile9.write(byte9.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile10.write(byte10.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile1.close()
                     binFile2.close()
                     binFile3.close()
                     binFile4.close()
                     binFile5.close()
                     binFile6.close()
                     binFile7.close()
                     binFile8.close()
                     binFile9.close()
                     binFile10.close()
                elif numfiles == 11: 
                     byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                     byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)    
                     byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)     
                     byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
                     byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)    
                     byte6 = int(vec_str[47:39:-1],2)
                     byte7 = int(vec_str[55:47:-1],2)
                     byte8 = int(vec_str[63:55:-1],2)
                     byte9 = int(vec_str[71:63:-1],2)
                     byte10 = int(vec_str[79:71:-1],2)    
                     byte11 = int(vec_str[87:79:-1],2)
                     binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile5.write(byte5.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile6.write(byte6.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile7.write(byte7.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile8.write(byte8.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile9.write(byte9.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile10.write(byte10.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile11.write(byte11.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile1.close()
                     binFile2.close()
                     binFile3.close()
                     binFile4.close()
                     binFile5.close()
                     binFile6.close()
                     binFile7.close()
                     binFile8.close()
                     binFile9.close()
                     binFile10.close()
                     binFile11.close()
                elif numfiles == 12: 
                     byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                     byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)    
                     byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)     
                     byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
                     byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)    
                     byte6 = int(vec_str[47:39:-1],2)
                     byte7 = int(vec_str[55:47:-1],2)
                     byte8 = int(vec_str[63:55:-1],2)
                     byte9 = int(vec_str[71:63:-1],2)
                     byte10 = int(vec_str[79:71:-1],2)    
                     byte11 = int(vec_str[87:79:-1],2)   
                     byte12 = int(vec_str[95:87:-1],2)
                     binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile5.write(byte5.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile6.write(byte6.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile7.write(byte7.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile8.write(byte8.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile9.write(byte9.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile10.write(byte10.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile11.write(byte11.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile12.write(byte12.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile1.close()
                     binFile2.close()
                     binFile3.close()
                     binFile4.close()
                     binFile5.close()
                     binFile6.close()
                     binFile7.close()
                     binFile8.close()
                     binFile9.close()
                     binFile10.close()
                     binFile11.close()
                     binFile12.close()
                elif numfiles == 13: 
                     byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                     byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)    
                     byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)     
                     byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
                     byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)    
                     byte6 = int(vec_str[47:39:-1],2)
                     byte7 = int(vec_str[55:47:-1],2)
                     byte8 = int(vec_str[63:55:-1],2)
                     byte9 = int(vec_str[71:63:-1],2)
                     byte10 = int(vec_str[79:71:-1],2)    
                     byte11 = int(vec_str[87:79:-1],2)   
                     byte12 = int(vec_str[95:87:-1],2)
                     byte13 = int(vec_str[103:95:-1],2)
                     binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile5.write(byte5.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile6.write(byte6.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile7.write(byte7.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile8.write(byte8.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile9.write(byte9.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile10.write(byte10.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile11.write(byte11.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile12.write(byte12.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile13.write(byte13.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile1.close()
                     binFile2.close()
                     binFile3.close()
                     binFile4.close()
                     binFile5.close()
                     binFile6.close()
                     binFile7.close()
                     binFile8.close()
                     binFile9.close()
                     binFile10.close()
                     binFile11.close()
                     binFile12.close()
                     binFile13.close()
                elif numfiles == 14: 
                     byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                     byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)    
                     byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)     
                     byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
                     byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)    
                     byte6 = int(vec_str[47:39:-1],2)
                     byte7 = int(vec_str[55:47:-1],2)
                     byte8 = int(vec_str[63:55:-1],2)
                     byte9 = int(vec_str[71:63:-1],2)
                     byte10 = int(vec_str[79:71:-1],2)    
                     byte11 = int(vec_str[87:79:-1],2)   
                     byte12 = int(vec_str[95:87:-1],2)
                     byte13 = int(vec_str[103:95:-1],2)
                     byte14 = int(vec_str[111:103:-1],2)
                     binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile5.write(byte5.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile6.write(byte6.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile7.write(byte7.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile8.write(byte8.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile9.write(byte9.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile10.write(byte10.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile11.write(byte11.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile12.write(byte12.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile13.write(byte13.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile14.write(byte14.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile1.close()
                     binFile2.close()
                     binFile3.close()
                     binFile4.close()
                     binFile5.close()
                     binFile6.close()
                     binFile7.close()
                     binFile8.close()
                     binFile9.close()
                     binFile10.close()
                     binFile11.close()
                     binFile12.close()
                     binFile13.close()
                     binFile14.close()
                elif numfiles == 15: 
                     byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2)    
                     byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)    
                     byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)     
                     byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
                     byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)    
                     byte6 = int(vec_str[47:39:-1],2)
                     byte7 = int(vec_str[55:47:-1],2)
                     byte8 = int(vec_str[63:55:-1],2)
                     byte9 = int(vec_str[71:63:-1],2)
                     byte10 = int(vec_str[79:71:-1],2)    
                     byte11 = int(vec_str[87:79:-1],2)   
                     byte12 = int(vec_str[95:87:-1],2)
                     byte13 = int(vec_str[103:95:-1],2)
                     byte14 = int(vec_str[111:103:-1],2)
                     byte15 = int(vec_str[119:111:-1],2)
                     binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile5.write(byte5.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile6.write(byte6.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile7.write(byte7.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile8.write(byte8.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile9.write(byte9.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile10.write(byte10.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile11.write(byte11.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile12.write(byte12.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile13.write(byte13.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile14.write(byte14.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile15.write(byte15.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                     binFile1.close()
                     binFile2.close()
                     binFile3.close()
                     binFile4.close()
                     binFile5.close()
                     binFile6.close()
                     binFile7.close()
                     binFile8.close()
                     binFile9.close()
                     binFile10.close()
                     binFile11.close()
                     binFile12.close()
                     binFile13.close()
                     binFile14.close()
                     binFile15.close()
```

Comment: 80% of your code seems to be irrelevant to the problem. please create a *minimal* example that reproduces the faulty behavior. And speaking of: *what exactly* is the faulty behavior you are experiencing? You just described what you want it to do, but you don't tell, what it actually does? Are the files written to a wrong location? Are there no files written at all?

Comment: no files written at all